# IE 10 special characters

Tags: internet-explorer, special-characters, internet-explorer-10

I'm  using a Windows 8 64 bit laptop with IE 10 installed.

I have a problem regarding special characters in IE 10. My OS is English however I'm  using a Turkish keyboard.

Now in Chrome, Firefox I absolutely have no problem but in IE 10 any kind of text input I get other characters when I try to type some special characters in Turkish:

For example:

"Fıstıkçı Şahap" is what can I write in Chrome but in IE the same entry shows as:

"f1st1kç1 _ahap"

So I get "1" instead of "ı" and "_" instead of "ş".

Why do you think this is happening and what is the solution?

Comment: *Where* are you typing them? In an input area on a web page? If this happens on *all* pages, then it is problem with your browser and its settings. If it happens on some specific page, please post enough code (HTML and CSS) that lets anyone reconstruct the issue.

Comment: It happens on all pages and yes in an input area (example Google search)

Comment: What seems to happen is that some bytes lose their most significant byte. E.g., when you have the dotless i “ı” in UTF-16 encoding (the internal encoding in Windows), it is 131 hexadecimal. Drop the leading bit and you get 31, which is the code for “1”. Similarly, “ş” is 15F and turns to 5F, “_”. *Why* this happens is a different issue and appears to be off-topic at SO. It would be on-topic at SuperUser. What puzzles me is why “ç” is preserved.

Comment: That's really interesting. I'll post the same question there.